How can I use the same test_helper function in integration tests and unit tests in rust?
So I have an integration test /tests/my_test.rs and a unit test in /src/some_module/function.rs. If I create a test helper in
/tests/test_helper.rs



pub struct TestHelper {
}
impl TestHelper {
    fn meaning(&self) -> i32 {
        42
    }
}

I can figure out to use it in the /tests/my_test.rs
use super::test_helper::TestHelper;

#[test]
fn test_helper_works() {
    let helper = TestHelper::new();
    assert_eq!(helper.meaning(), 42);
}

But I cannot figure out how to access it from /src/some_module/function.rs in a mod tests block
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use super::test_helper::TestHelper;

    #[test]
    fn some_old_test() {
        let helper = TestHelper::new();
        assert_eq!(helper.meaning(), 42);
    }
}

I've tried putting the helper in /src/test_helpers/ using #[cfg(test)] but that allowed it in the unit tests but not the integration tests any way I could think to include it.

I expect the issue has to do with each test file in tests being wrapped in its own crate? I think that is how it works but I don't know how you reach into those crates from the src/ tree. Likewise, anything I put in the src tree with a #[cfg(test)] conditional compilation is not found from the tests directory.

Two workaround ideas: 1) use the include! macro to include the helper source code in both places 2) unconditionally export the helper with #[doc(hidden)]

Or use #[path = "..."] mod utils;, or create a separate dev-dependency crate.

@FinnBear with #[doc(hidden)] it will still be in the release build but not visible correct? And with include I just have to watch changing the relative paths because it probably won't refactor nicely?

@ChayimFriedman ok, that worked! Again, I need to be careful refactoring paths because my IDE probably won't refactor properly but it does solve the problem!
in my particular case where I was using slint, the helpers were using the structure created by the slint build.rs so could not easily be transferred to its own crate.
